# ASP.NET - Help to understand this block of code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to understand a block of code from a school project, but I'm not understanding what this does.

I know that this is a controller method and is passing some information to the view?

Can you help me?

```
public ActionResult Index(int ? page, string sort) {
  using(istecEntities ctx = new istecEntities()) {
    var Persons = ctx.Persons.ToList()
      .Select(p => new Person {
          Num = p.num,
          Name = p.Name,
          Area = p.Area,
          Grades = p.Grades as List <Grade>
      }).ToList<Person>();

    switch (sort) {
    case "numdesc":
      Persons = Persons.OrderByDescending(p =>p.Num).ToList<Person>();
      break;
    case "NameDesc":
      Persons = Persons.OrderByDescending(p =>p.Name).ToList<Person>();
      break;
    case "NameAsc":
      Persons = Persons.OrderBy(p =>p.Name).ToList<Person>();
      break;
    default:
      Persons = Persons.OrderBy(p =>p.Num).ToList<Person>();
      break;
    }
    ViewBag.sortnum = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sort)) ? 
         "numdesc": "";
    ViewBag.sortName = (sort == "NameDesc") ? 
         "NameAsc": "NameDesc";
    ViewBag.sort = sort;
    int size = 3;
    int pagenumber = (page ?? 1);
    return View(Persons.ToPagedList<Person>(pagenumber, size));
  }
}
```

Comment: Its basically taking a page number and sort (I'm guessing from the View) and then displaying the list of Person (Objects) in that order based on the sort.  What line/lines do you not fully understand?  Might be worth reading simple c# LINQ and MVC tutorial.

Comment: @AliK Thanks for the answer. I don't understand what is that &quot, probably something from the view?  The 3rd line is getting all the entities from the Model?

Comment: You've got a lot of HTML entities in the code, probably from copy/paste. &quote; and &gt; need to be translated to display properly on Stackoverflow.

Comment: That should be the correct code after replacing the HTML entities with the matching character

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad. Thanks for the edit @Steve

Comment: There are also a couple of questionable lines. What is the reason to have a select to build a list of Person from a List of Person? Then all those ToList makes the final ToPagedList almost useless. ToList materializes all the data in memory and thus ToPagedList loses its advantage

Comment: To be honest I don't know. This is a block of code that my teacher put on one of his exames and is asking to explain the code. Now I understand a little better, for example, the switch is to sort according to the sort parameter.  The ternary operatores I understand too, except the ```int pagenumber = (page ?? 1);``` . And then, the ```using``` and the ```var Persons => ...``` I don't.

Comment: The ?? is the [null coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) while the using handles a disposable object (something that you need to dispose when you finish to use it) So your _istecEntities_ is probably a derived instance of a DbContext used by [EntityFramework](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core.aspx) to access a database and create objects from the database tables